# Call Variables From For Loop

Tags: python, list, append, nested-lists

I have been trying to iterate through a for loop to call variables from strings, is this something that can be done?

I want to have some code that works as so.

```
empleado0 = ["Diego Mondragón", 1, 50, "M"]
empleado1 = ["Juan Esteban Aristizabal", 1, 37, "M"]
```

I was going to use this list to merge both lists.

```
nomina=[]
```

This is where the error occurs, I have tried %d and +i but it does not work.

```
for i in range(2):
    nomina.append(empleado'i')
print(nomina)
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can't add `empleado[i]` because that would be name, gender etc.
Every time you have a new employee, assign it to the same variable `empleado` and in the loop append it to `nomina`. You don't want to have variables in your code like `empleado1` etc, because that won't work if the number of employees changes.

```
nomina=[]

empleado=["Diego Mondragón", 1, 50, "M"]
nomina.append(empleado)


empleado=["Juan Esteban Aristizabal", 1, 37, "M"]
nomina.append(empleado)

for em in nomina:
    print(em)
```

output:

```
['Diego Mondragón', 1, 50, 'M']
['Juan Esteban Aristizabal', 1, 37, 'M']
```

---

Say you read from a file

```
 Diego Mondragon, 1, 50, 'M'
 Juan Esteban Aristizabal, 1, 37, 'M'
```

into a list `lines`.

```
f = open("c:/test.txt",'r')
lines=f.readlines()
lines
```

output:

```
["Diego Mondragon, 1, 50, 'M'\n", "Juan Esteban Aristizabal, 1, 37, 'M'\n"]
```

Now get rid of extra linebreak and check the type of each line:

```
for l in lines:
    l=l.strip()   
    print(l, type(l))
```

output:

```
Diego Mondragon, 1, 50, 'M' <class 'str'>
Juan Esteban Aristizabal, 1, 37, 'M' <class 'str'>
```

So we have cleaned up, and know the resulting line is a string. But each substring still has extra spaces, that we should remove:

```
# turn string into list
empleado = lines[0].strip().split(',')
print(empleado)

#clean up extra spaces
emp2=[]
for e in empleado:
    emp2.append(e.strip())
    
print(emp2)
```

output:

```
['Diego Mondragon', ' 1', ' 50', " 'M'"]
['Diego Mondragon', '1', '50', "'M'"]
```

Putting it all together :

```
f = open("c:/test.txt",'r')
lines=f.readlines()
nomina=[]

for l in lines:
    l=l.strip()
    empleado=l.split(',')
    emp2=[]
    for e in empleado:
        emp2.append(e.strip())
    nomina.append(emp2)
    
    
print(nomina)
```

output:

```
[['Diego Mondragon', '1', '50', "'M'"], ['Juan Esteban Aristizabal', '1', '37', "'M'"]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. If I want to save dynamically each one of the list values, i.e. reading from a file, or to perform other structured tasks, is there a way to create a variable name from a prefix name + postfix using an incremental value or similar? It is very useful in C language...

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea (proliferation of variables) and there is no known need for it.  Just make a loop where you read from the file into the variable `empleado` and append to `nomina`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
empleado0=["Diego Mondragón", 1, 50, "M"]
empleado1=["Juan Esteban Aristizabal", 1, 37, "M"]
nomina = []
nomina = [v for k,v in globals().items() if k.startswith('empleado')]
print(nomina)
```